# Where can I ask a question about the legality of devilution?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, legal

I want to know if it's legal for this repository to exist:

https://github.com/diasurgical/devilution

I was checking out the following Stack Exchange sites:

- https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
- https://law.stackexchange.com/

I am not sure which one to post it to. I want to know if reverse engineering a game that's under the IP of Blizzard is legal. People are saying it's not legal, because of intellectual rights, and some people are saying it's legal, because Diablo is technically "discontinued".

Comment: I'm not a community member there, so take this with a grain of salt and visit their help center first, but that sounds like a question for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). You might need to generalize the question first though since asking about specific cases is off topic there.

Comment: Haha @Magisch well I'm happy I posted it here first then lol. Would have done my Electrical Engineering fiasco thing all over again :P   I will see what I can do

Comment: @Magisch I thought the "specific cases" was about asking for legal advice. In this case, it seems a specific case that the asker is not involved with. It would be nice if someone familiar with Law.SE could chime in here.

Comment: Anyone who continues to downvote, I'll just delete my topic. Please don't, thank you